# Divert a value in Shell Script

Tags: unix, shell

I have the following code but I didn't understand

the [ $val -eq 0 ] 2 part. What does the two (2) there for?

```
#!/bin/bash 
val=0 
while [ $val -eq 0 ] 2> /dev/null; do 
    read -p "Please enter a value: " val 
done 
echo "You didn't enter 0!"
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means standard error, i.e. redirect any error message to /dev/null which basically means don't display any error message that would show up in the redirected command.

Answer (score 1):

```
What does the two (2) there for?
```

`2` means `stderr` stream